# meteor simple reactive var

Tags: meteor, var, reactive

I'm working in meteor trying to use a reactive var to switch the content in the main panel between two tabs. I've been able to test the content successfully on it's own so I'm fairly confident the issue lies in the reactive var code. Specifically I think the issue is with the tab: function() but after many searches and reading documentation I haven't found a solution.

The relevant js:

```
Template.content.onCreated( function() {
   this.currentTab = new ReactiveVar('form');
});

Template.content.helpers({
   tab: function() {
       return Template.instance().currentTab.get();
   }
});

Template.content.events({
  'click .nav li': function (event, template) {
      var currentTab = $( event.target ).closest( "li" );

      currentTab.addClass( "active" );
      $( ".nav li" ).not( currentTab ).removeClass( "active" );

      Template.currentTab.set();
  }
});
```

The relevant html:

```
<template name ="content">
    <ul class ="nav">
        <li data-template="form"><a href="#">Form</a></li>
        <li data-template="results"><a href="#">Results</a></li>
    </ul>
    {{ > Template.dynamic template=tab}}
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{{ > Template.dynamic template=tab}}
```

This is calling the `tab` helper to get a string that is the name of the template you want to show here. It should work the first time because you start out by setting the value of `currentTab` to "form".

To change the template that gets shown, you need to change the value of `currentTab` to a string matching the name of the new template. You're not doing that.

```
Template.currentTab.set();
```

This is where you should be doing that. Instead you're calling `set()` on the `currentTab` property of `Template`, which I don't think exists. `Template` with a capital T is a Meteor object, not the template instance that I think you're trying to refer to. And to set a new value for `currentTab`, you actually need to provide a value. Like so:

```
Template.content.events( {
    'click .nav li': function(event, instance) {
        //logic to decide which template you want to show
        //and put the name of that template in templateName

        instance.currentTab.set(templateName)
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! That makes a lot more sense. Still not working fully but helpful to understand it better. 

You say it should work the first time, it never shows anything but the navigation bar. If I put in the form or results template manually it works but not when I use tab. Any insights?

Comment: Do you have a template named "form" that you're expecting to show up where `Template.dynamic` is?